# UITableView keeps autoscrolling to top

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When the user tries scrolling down the table (goes past the keyboard height), it automatically scrolls back to the top of table, leaving the user unable to press any of the keys in the bottoms rows of the table. How do I disable this autoscroll to top? Note this is different from the scrollsToTop property.

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var tableView: UITableView = UITableView()
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds


let buttonTitles = [
    "XX",
    "YY"
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight - 40)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self,forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    self.view.addSubview(tableView)


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.buttonTitles.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.buttonTitles[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 14)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 176/255, green: 15/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1.0)
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var string = buttonTitles[indexPath.row]
    (textDocumentProxy as! UIKeyInput).insertText("\(string)")
}
```

Comment: Show more code. There must be sth wrong outside viewDidLoad.

Comment: are you setting the contentOffset or contentInsets anywhere in that viewController?

Comment: @kostek - thanks - just provided everything in the .swift file

Answer (score 0):

Move your code except

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

to viewWillAppear

Comment: Assuming I did this right (see below) - that didn't work:   `override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height
        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight - 40)
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self,forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    }`

Comment: have you added any constraints to your table view??

Comment: Sorry - I'm new to this, but assumed that tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight - 40) was sufficient information to place the view without any additional constraints